# Combine internal and external bibliography references

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

I have a file `one.tex` that contains its own bibliography from `ref1.bib`.

I don't believe the following fact is relevant to the current problem but just in case: This bibliography is split up according to type through `\printbibliography`.

This is `one.tex`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, defernumbers=true, maxnames=10, sorting=ydnt, sortcites=true, style=ieee, citestyle=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref1.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1 Text}
blablbalbalabla~\cite{citation2}. blablablaba~\cite{citation7, citation6, citation4}.blablab~\cite{citation7}

\section{Section 2 bibliography}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title={Refereed Contributions in Journals},heading=subbibliography,type=article]

\printbibliography[title={Refereed Full Paper Contributions in Conferences}, heading=subbibliography, type=inproceedings]

\printbibliography[title={Refereed Short Paper Contributions in Conferences \& Workshops}, heading=subbibliography, type=incollection]

\section{Section 3 more text}
blablbalbalabla~\cite{citation6, citation7, citation3}.
blablablaba~\cite{citation4}.blablaba~\cite{citation7}.
blablabla~\cite{citation1}

\end{document}
```

and here is bib1.bib

```
@article{citation1,
author={X Y and A B and T Y},
title={Just repeating the same title again and again},
journal = {IEEE Journal},
year={2016}
}

@article{citation5,
author={X Y and A B and T Y},
title={Just repeating the same title again and again},
journal = {IEEE Journal},
year={2014}
}

@inproceedings{citation2,
author={X Y and A B and T Y},
title={Just repeating the same title again and again},
booktitle= {Proceedings of the aweosme conference},
year={2016},
}

@inproceedings{citation3,
author={X Y and A B and T Y},
title={Just repeating the same title again and again},
booktitle= {Proceedings of the aweosme conference},
year={2016},
}

@inproceedings{citation4,
author={X Y and A B and T Y},
title={Just repeating the same title again and again},
booktitle= {Proceedings of the aweosme conference},
year={2015},
}

@incollection{citation5,
author={X Y and A B and T Y},
title={Just repeating the same title again and again},
booktitle= {Proceedings of the aweosme conference},
year={2012},
}


@incollection{citation6,
author={X Y and A B and T Y},
title={Just repeating the same title again and again},
booktitle= {Proceedings of the aweosme conference},
year={2016},
}

@incollection{citation7,
author={X Y and A B and T Y},
title={Just repeating the same title again and again},
booktitle= {Proceedings of the aweosme conference},
year={2016},
}
```

I now have a second file two.tex that also contains its own bibliography from `ref2.bib`. Now, in the text in `two.tex`, I might have `\cite{ref1}` and `\cite{ref2}` where `ref1` is a reference from the bibliography of `one.tex` while `ref2` is from the current file's bibliography `bib2`
It is important that the number that appears for `ref1` corresponds to its number in the compiled bibliography of `one.pdf`.
I tried using the `xcite` package by first compiling `one.tex` (`pdflatex` followed by `bibtex` followed by `pdflatex`) and then using `\externalcitedocument{one}` in `two.tex`, but all references that refer to `bib1` are still undefined. In the following example, the first citation works while the second one referring to the bibliography from the other file is still undefined.

Here is `two.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcite}
\externalcitedocument{one}

\begin{document}

Here is some text that will reference something from the current document~\cite{ref2-1}, as well as something from the first document~\cite{citation6}.

\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{ref2}

\end{document}
```

and here is `ref2.bib`

```
@article{ref2-1,
author={X Y and A B and T Y},
title={This is a ref 2 title},
journal = {IEEE Journal},
year={2016}
}

@article{ref2-2,
author={X Y and A B and T Y},
title={This is a ref 2 title},
journal = {IEEE Journal},
year={2014}
}
```

Am I using `xcite` incorrectly?

Comment: Please post two minimal(!) files that attempt to do what you want. It is tedious and time-consuming for others to create two separate files with two separate sets of bibliography items just to test.

Comment: Welcome! What do you mean when you say that each file contains its own bibliography? Do you mean each contains `\bibliographystyle{}\bibliography{<filename>}`? Also relevant: is Biblatex/Biber an option? It can handle multiple bibliographies (relatively) easily.

Comment: I just edited my question with a full example. I could have minimized the first file more but I'm not sure if using the printbibliography in combination with the biber backend might also be contributing to the issue here.

Comment: It seems `xcite` does not work with `biblatex`.

Comment: Thanks Guido. Do you have any suggestions on what to use instead to get the same effect of the divided bibliography in the first document? I'm also surprised xcite doesn't work with biblatex since its documentation says "Notice that \bibitem commands may not appear
in aaa.tex, but rather in aaa.bbl if BibTEX or Biber are used to generate the
bibliography, but this doesn’t matter. The important thing is that aaa.tex is in
final form with all citations resolved and that aaa.aux is readable."

Comment: My guess is that it might have worked for a very previous version of `biblatex`. There were many changes in `biblatex` in the past 5 years.

Comment: @SarahNadi -- The reference to `aaa.aux` is concerning (nowadays) for Biber-based bibliographies. While BibTeX relies on the `.aux` file, Biber requires a `.bcf` file.

Comment: We may ask @egreg, who is the author of `xcite` package, if there is a way to make it work with BibLaTeX...

Comment: @CarLaTeX, that would be great -- I hope he gives me some hints. I still couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @SarahNadi `xcite` doesn't work with `biblatex` generated references.

Answer (score 4):

`xcite` does not work with `biblatex` generated `.aux` files.

***For this particular case*** you can do with

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcite}
\makeatletter
\def\abx@aux@number#1#2#3#4#5#6\XC@{\bibcite{#2}{#5}}
\long\def\XC@test#1#2#3#4\XC@{%
  \ifx#1\bibcite
    \bibcite{\XC@prefix#2}{#3}%
  \else
    \ifx#1\abx@aux@number
      \abx@aux@number{#2}{#3}#4\XC@
    \else
      \ifx#1\@input
        \edef\XC@list{\XC@list#2\relax}%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
  \ifeof\@inputcheck\expandafter\XC@aux
  \else\expandafter\XC@read\fi}
\makeatother

\externalcitedocument{one}

\begin{document}

Here is some text that will reference something from the current 
document~\cite{ref2-1}, as well as something from the first 
document~\cite{citation6}.

\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{ref2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @egreg but it still didn't work for me. Did you use biber for the first document?

Comment: @SarahNadi Yes, of course.