# How to use refsection and xcite together?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I have a main document called `main.tex` involving multiple `refsection` environments.
I have some figures that are compiled separately and are to be placed in some of these `refsection`s.
Let us say `Fig1.tex` creates `Fig1.pdf` that should appear in the first `refsection` of `main.tex`.

I am trying to use `xcite` to import citations from the `main.tex` to `Fig1.tex`.
But while compiling `Fig1.tex` none of my citations are recognised.
I understand that this is because in `Fig1.tex` I have no way to specify which refsection to use to `xcite`.

Are there any suggestions to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can see `xcite` is not compatible with `biblatex` (which isn't really surprising given that `biblatex` reimplements the entire citation and bibliography handling completely). There are clever ways to get a `biblatex`–BibTeX bridge going with `xcite` as shown by egreg in [Combine internal and external bibliography references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/338701/35864). But as far as I am aware there is no `biblatex`–`biblatex` functionality for `xcite`.

In principle you can apply my solution to [How to import / print a bibliography created from a separate / external document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/426964/35864).
Essentially, that code just loads all the bibliography and citation information from the parent document (`main.tex` or `maindoc.tex`) and makes it available to the child (`Fig1.tex` or `coverletter.tex`). The child itself can only consume the information, it can not engage in influencing it.

There are a few caveats to the solution presented there

1. Both the parent and the child document must load `biblatex` with the same options (*some* options could be varied, but those that have an impact on the `.bbl` can't be).
2. You can only cite entries in the child document that were cited (or `\nocite`d) in the parent document.
3. Furthermore, the citations in the child document will be treated as non-existent in the parent document, i.e. they do not influence the sort order in `sorting=none` contexts, they don't increment any citation counters, they don't interact with 'ibid.' trackers.
4. The citations in the child document can only be taken from reference contexts in which they appear in the parent document.

For `refsection`s you need to manually tell the child document which `refsection` to use. Fortunately, that is quite simple: You just have to set a counter called `refsection` (e.g. `\setcounter{refsection}{3}` in the example below). In order to be able to do that properly, you need to find out the correct `refsection` from the parent document. The command `\therefsection` can help you there (if you don't want to count the relevant commands on your own).

`main.tex`

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\newrefsection
This is refsetcion~\therefsection

\cite{sigfridsson,vizedom:related}
\printbibliography

\newrefsection
This is refsetcion~\therefsection

\cite{sigfridsson,worman}
\printbibliography

\newrefsection
This is refsetcion~\therefsection

\cite{sigfridsson,geer}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

`external.tex` with `\importbibfrom{<parent base name>}` and `\setcounter{refsection}{<relevant refsection>}`

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\importbibfrom}[1]{%
  \def\blx@bblfile{%
    \blx@secinit
    \begingroup
    \blx@bblstart
    \InputIfFileExists{#1.bbl}
      {\blx@info@noline{... file '#1.bbl' found}%
       \global\toggletrue{blx@bbldone}}
      {\blx@info@noline{... file '#1.bbl' not found}%
       \typeout{No file #1.bbl.}}%
    \blx@bblend
    \endgroup
    % global sorting as this is called at BeginDocument
    \csnumgdef{blx@labelnumber@\the\c@refsection}{0}}}

\global\let\blx@rerun@biber\relax
\makeatother

\importbibfrom{main}

\setcounter{refsection}{3}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\end{document}
```

Run the usual compilation cycle on `main.tex`

```
pdflatex main
biber main
pdflatex main
pdflatex main
```

Then run only LaTeX on `external.tex`

```
pdflatex external
pdflatex external
```

---

**NB** Note that this solution will not work if you have `defernumbers` enabled. That is because `defernumbers` needs the `.aux` file to process the label numbers properly. The solution above only reads the `.bbl` and not the `.aux`.

To make `defernumbers` work we can redirect the relevant bit of the `.aux` file from the parent to a different file (`.naux`) and read that in the child document. (Another solution would be to read the entire `.aux` file of the parent and only execute the relevant label number commands and skipping over the rest. That would be similar to what `xcite` does and would moreover not require additional code in the parent file - it would, however, require that I understand how this method/`xcite` works in more detail, so I went with what you can see below.)

Add

```
\makeatletter
\newwrite\blxconi@numaux@out

\AtEndDocument{%
  \begingroup
  \immediate\openout\blxconi@numaux@out\jobname.naux\relax
  \iftoggle{blx@defernumbers}
    {\iftoggle{blx@runbiber}
      {}
      {\def\do#1{\blx@auxwrite\blxconi@numaux@out{}{#1}}
       \dolistloop\blx@localnumaux}}
    {}%
  \immediate\closeout\blxconi@numaux@out
  \endgroup}
\makeatother
```

to the parent document and use

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\blxconi@readdefernums}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \@input{#1.naux}%
  \makeatother
  \endgroup}

\newcommand*{\importbibfrom}[1]{%
  \def\blx@bblfile{%
    \blx@secinit
    \begingroup
    \blx@bblstart
    \InputIfFileExists{#1.bbl}
      {\blx@info@noline{... file '#1.bbl' found}%
       \global\toggletrue{blx@bbldone}}
      {\blx@info@noline{... file '#1.bbl' not found}%
       \typeout{No file #1.bbl.}}%
    \blx@bblend
    \endgroup
    % global sorting as this is called at BeginDocument
    \csnumgdef{blx@labelnumber@\the\c@refsection}{0}}%
  \blxconi@readdefernums{#1}}

\global\let\blx@rerun@biber\relax
\makeatother
```

instead of the definition from above for the child document.

Comment: The OP can't comment here but https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54719495#54719495