# Reusing bibliography for volatile/ online sources

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

A paper I am currently writing references some online sources I'd like to snapshot for reference.
My bib file could be enhanced to include `file` entries for such saved snapshots.

I was wondering if/how I could use the output of the main document to create a second document acting as an index for the snapshots.
Ideally one would open the index PDF and have just the subset of references with `file` entries which could be clicked on to access the snapshot.

Unfortunately searching the internet didn't prove that helpful using keywords as `biblatex, reuse, bibliogpraphy`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official interface to reuse the bibliography from a different document directly. Of course you can use the same `.bib` file, but that is by for not enough to get exactly the same output as another document.

In [How to import / print a bibliography created from a separate / external document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/426964/35864) and [How to use refsection and xcite together?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/473444/35864) you can find a strategy to reuse the bibliography of another document by reading its `.bbl` file. In principle this might help you here as well. There are a lot of caveats attached to this strategy, but those appear to be acceptable for what you have in mind.

Assume the parent file `myparent.tex` looks roughly like this

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  url       = {https://example.edu/~elk/bronto.pdf},
  file      = {./elk-bronto.pdf},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,elk,worman,markey}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Several bibliography entries.]

Then you can use `\importbibfrom` as defined in the links to import the `.bbl` file of `myparent` into a child document. (Note that for that to work either both documents must live in the same working directory or you must manually copy `myparent.bbl` into the same directory as the child document.)

With the data from the parent file imported, it is just a matter of printing the `file` field (which is ignored by default) and filtering only those entries with a `file` field.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  file = {file archived at},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{file}{\bibstring{file}\addspace\url{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \newunit
  \printfield{file}%
  \finentry}

\defbibcheck{hasfile}{%
  \iffieldundef{file}{\skipentry}{}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\importbibfrom}[1]{%
  \def\blx@bblfile{%
    \blx@secinit
    \begingroup
    \blx@bblstart
    \InputIfFileExists{#1.bbl}
      {\blx@info@noline{... file '#1.bbl' found}%
       \global\toggletrue{blx@bbldone}}
      {\blx@info@noline{... file '#1.bbl' not found}%
       \typeout{No file #1.bbl.}}%
    \blx@bblend
    \endgroup
    % global sorting as this is called at BeginDocument
    \csnumgdef{blx@labelnumber@\the\c@refsection}{0}}}

\global\let\blx@rerun@biber\relax
\makeatother

\importbibfrom{myparent}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography[check=hasfile]
\end{document}
```

[image: Only one entry with file field.]

Comment: Many, many thanks! This solution is awesome! It does exactly what I wanted. I had to change one minor thing though: `\DeclareFieldFormat{file}{\bibstring{file}\addspace\url{#1}}` didn't work for me with hyperref. Changing it to `\DeclareFieldFormat{file}{\bibstring{file}\addspace\href{./#1}{#1}}` solved it and the referenced file opens in TexStudio (SumatraPDF fails but this is due to a current bug in 3.2)