# Reuse .bbl file from biber in another document

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, bbl

I would like to generate a `.bbl` file once and then reuse that instead of re-running `biber` for each file. This way all the references should have same numbering. I have a file `complete-bibliography.tex`, which has all my `.bib` entries.  I run

```
pdflatex complete-bibliography.tex
biber complete-bibliography 
pdflatex complete-bibliography.tex
```

This yields `complete-bibliography.bbl` and the bibliography, as desired:
[image]

However, when I attempt to use `complete-bibliography.bbl` in `test.tex` via

```
\input{complete-bibliography.bbl}
```

I get

> Undefined control sequence.
> \datalist

Seems like I am missing something very obvious, but not seeing it...

#### `complete-bibliography.tex`

```
\begin{filecontents*}{complete-bibliography.bib}
@book{goossens93,
    author   ={Michel Goossens},
    title    ={The {LaTeX} Companion},
    year     ={1993},
    publisher={Addison-Wesley},
    address  ={Reading, Massachusetts},
}

@article{greenwade93, 
    author ={George D. Greenwade},
    title  ={The {C}omprehensive {TeX} {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})},
    year   ={1993},
    journal={TUGBoat},
    volume ={14},
    number ={3},
    pages  ={342--351},
    url    ={www.ctan.org},
}

@book{knuth79,
    author   ={Donald E. Knuth},
    title    ={{TeX} and Metafont, New Directions in Typesetting},
    year     ={1979},
    publisher={American Mathematical Society and Digital Press},
    address  ={Stanford},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{complete-bibliography.bib}

\begin{document} 
This is a dummy document used to generate the .bbl file
for \emph{all} references.

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

#### `test.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{complete-bibliography.bib}% <-- Not needed here

\begin{document} 
This document reads the previously generated .bbl file.

%% Other .tex files should be able to use this .bbl
\IfFileExists{complete-bibliography.bbl}{%
    \input{complete-bibliography.bbl}
}{}%
\fullcite{knuth79}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/426964/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/473444/35864.

Comment: why don't you use once `\nocite{*}` in the document?

Comment: ah sorry, you want to read in a bbl with a different name. Well you could try to redefine \jobname before begin document, but imho the time gain is not worth the trouble. It would be easier to use a small script which first copy your bbl and give it the name of your current document (and this assumes that the biblatex version didn't change).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Copying the file seems to work. So what magic happens if the .bbl file has a same name? I'd prefer not to make thousands of copies of the file if I can avoid it.

Comment: @moewe: Looks like that works as well. Not sure why that is not needed if the .bbl has the same file name as `\jobname` though.

Comment: Like with other auxiliary files (`.aux`, `.toc` etc.), `biblatex` just tries to input `\jobname.bbl` if it is there. So if your file has the right name, it is read. If it has the right data format and contains the necessary information, everything will work regardless of how the file was produced. If it does not have the predefined name, tricks like the one in the linked Q&A are necessary to load the differently named file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Can you add an answer as the copying the `.bbl` file may be helpful to others. If you add it to the [How to import / print a bibliography created from a separate / external document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/426964/4301), this question can be closed as a duplicate.